# Creating a basic project template with Vue, TS, and nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, project-management, vue-cli

I’m trying to figure out how to use vue cli. I have an idea for a project and would like to use the follow tech: vueJS, Typecript, and nodeJS(expressJS, socket.io)

How do I go about creating a template with all the config/json/vue files. There are just so many files and they need to be in specific places it gets confusing!

Does anyone know if a template for these types of projects? Or better yet a way to generate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The way to create a new project template with Vue-CLI is by using the [`vue create` command](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create). You can set your own techstack from there. If you need a more opinionated template, you can use the resources below.

Most well-known and detailed vue boilerplate around:

https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate

---

If it's too advanced/extensive for your project, there are plenty of examples/templates here:

https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#examples

Comment: Thank you this is perfect. Is there not a way to create a project template with vue-CLI?

Comment: With Vue-CLI you can use `vue create <project-name>` to create an empty template with the correct tech stack. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create 

If you need a more fleshed out template, use one the more opinionated boilerplates from my answer as inspiration.